# Incrementing Serial Number in PDF Creation - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, pdf, itext

I am generating a PDF using ITextSharp in ASP.NET. I need to display a table, with some data and Serial No auto incremented. I tried the following (using loop - increment) but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Dim dsGetStudentFeeDetails = dbl.usp_GetFeeReceiptDetailsForStudent(sid).AsQueryable

        For Each f1 In dsGetStudentFeeDetails
            Dim i As Integer = 1
            stuName = New PdfPCell(FormatPhrase(i))
            'stuName.Colspan = 4
            'stuName.Border = 0
            stuName.NoWrap = True
            stuName.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
            pdftable4.AddCell(stuName)

            stuName = New PdfPCell(FormatPhrase(f1.FeeAmountPaidDate))
            'stuName.Colspan = 4
            'stuName.Border = 0
            stuName.NoWrap = True
            stuName.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
            pdftable4.AddCell(stuName)

            i = i + 1
        Next
```

When I run through this during execution, I noticed that the `i = i + 1` doesn't get incremented. Why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to declare and set default value Above for loop use below code

```
Dim dsGetStudentFeeDetails = dbl.usp_GetFeeReceiptDetailsForStudent(sid).AsQueryable
          Dim i As Integer = 1
        For Each f1 In dsGetStudentFeeDetails

            stuName = New PdfPCell(FormatPhrase(i))
            'stuName.Colspan = 4
            'stuName.Border = 0
            stuName.NoWrap = True
            stuName.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
            pdftable4.AddCell(stuName)

            stuName = New PdfPCell(FormatPhrase(f1.FeeAmountPaidDate))
            'stuName.Colspan = 4
            'stuName.Border = 0
            stuName.NoWrap = True
            stuName.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
            pdftable4.AddCell(stuName)

            i = i + 1
        Next
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I just noticed that! Thanks, +10 to you :)